# Implicit conversion to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I've trying to make an implicit conversion from a class that wraps a std::vector to std::vector, but I keep getting this error:

> error: conversion from 'const value_type {aka const MatrixRow}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector'

My class MatrixRow is defined like this:

```
template <typename NumericType>
class MatrixRow{
public:

    // a lot of other methods here
    //....
    //......
    explicit operator std::vector<NumericType>() {return row_;}
    //...
    //...

private:
    std::vector<NumericType> row_;
}
```

The error occurs when I try to make the following in other part of my code:

```
std::vector<NumericType> row = obj.matrix_[0]; //obj.matrix_[0] is an object of type MatrixRow<NumericType>
```

It is the first time that I'm using implicit conversions so probably I didn't understood how to use them properly. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `obj.matrix_`? Might it be `const`?

Comment: Ehm... you marked the conversion operator as `explicit`. Why do you think something you say is explicit should be implicit?

Comment: @Cubic It was Clion that suggested the keyword, it  said "must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions". This is one of those cases when you feel so ashamed. Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigoCustodio CLion is right (I think that's a clang-tidy suggestion?) - implicit conversions are usually bad. I'd argue explicit conversions aren't that great either most of the time. There are some proper use cases like expression templates, but generally having a named method is just better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your operator is `explicit`, you should use different syntax:

```
std::vector<NumericType> row(obj.matrix_[0]);
```

BTW, you may return const reference to avoid copy:

```
explicit operator const std::vector<NumericType>&() const {return row_;}
```